# Checking only email, not username

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which checks email availability from database, but it's only checking email and not username. I want to check both email and username, I tried to check them through the code below but it doesnt work.

What is wrong with the code?

```
<?php
require_once './config.php';
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    $fname = ($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = ($_POST["lname"]);
    $name = ($_POST["username"]);
    $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
    $email = ($_POST["email"]);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id and username = :username_id ";
    try {
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email);
        $stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if ($result[0]["count"] > 0) {
            echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorbox'>Incorrect Username or Password</div><br>";
        }  else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES " . "( :name, :pass, :email, :fname, :lname)";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski no error output it checks email but no username

Comment: Are you supposed to be comparing the database `username` value with the `$email` variable and not the `$name` variable?

Comment: edited but it still dont work @GeoffAtkins

Comment: Why `($_POST["username"]);` ? why not `$_POST["username"];` ?

Comment: try an echo of the vars your are binding to your sql or just echo your sql to ensure it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using and condition. If you use or condition means it will be fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id or username = :username_id ";
```

Comment: Oooppsss same time deleting mine... :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your SQL statement, you are checking that both email and username are together try changing your statement from

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id and username = :username_id "
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id or username = :username_id "
```

This should force a return of 1 whenever either the username or email appears proving that they are not unique

Answer (score 0):

Typographical error. This line should be replaced:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $email);
```

should be replaced with:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $name);
```

Comment: Maybe you want to replace the `and` in your SQL query with an `or`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an error here:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email); //ok 
$stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $email); //you bind with $email again .. is it normal ?

You should validate your $_POST datas with !empty i.e.:
if(!empty($_POST["email"]) $email = $_POST["email"]) ... because with your actual code you could make sql queries with empty $email = null
```